# Saving Files in Downloads Folder of Shared External Storage

Tags: android

I want to save files to Downloads folder of the External Storage in Android. As I am storing it in the shared public storage and as I dont want to save it in the internal storage(Scope Storage), how do I do it? I am asking this because **Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)** seems deprecated and I want to do something similar which supports from Android 11 too.

Comment: If you no need to do that automatically, you can allow user to decide where to save this showing save file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use system Download manager with such folder path:

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
```

and as you know you have to add your desired/suggested file name. So in a result you will get such function call:

```
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
```

below you can see some example of my usage of such system functionality:

```
val link = ""
 val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(link))
 .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
.setMimeType(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(link))
.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)

.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)

val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val downloadId = manager.enqueue(request)
val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)

var downloading = true
while (downloading) {
       val cursor: Cursor = manager.query(query)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
         downloading = false
          Toast.makeText(context, context.resources.getString(R.string.download_file_message, fileName), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
    cursor.close()
  }
```

you can also add some header if you will need it:

```
.addRequestHeader("header name", "")
```

I hope it will help you and solve your task :)

Comment: Your code will do a download indeed. But `var downloading = true
while (downloading)....` will block the gui. The user will already be notified by the notification. And for the rest you better implement a broadcast receiver. And... OP did not speak about download. Only about storing. Well lets see...

Comment: yes, your idea also good) and you are right - my code blocks gui. I will try to add receiver